# Bot telegram Java - Error con el método setText

Tags: java, intellij-idea, telegram

Buenas,

Hace poco me he interesado por los bots de Telegram y he empezado por hacer el típico bot ejemplo que ponen en todos lados para los principiantes. Pero al pasar el código al intellij, me ha dado error en el método .setText, este sería el src/MyAmazingBot

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
public class MyAmazingBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {


    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {

        String message_text = update.getMessage().getText();
        long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();

        SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
            .setChatId(chat_id)
            .setText(message_text);
        try {
            execute(message); // Sending our message object to user
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {

    return "MyAmazingBot";
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    // Return bot token from BotFather
    return "12345:qwertyuiopASDGFHKMK";
    }
}
```

Salta como:

> Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String)

Me gustaría saber si alguien se ha encontrado con un problema similar y como lo han solventado. Gracias.

PD: evidentemente, el token y el nombre del bot lo he reemplazado y demás.

Siento si la pregunta es muy obvia o algo tonta, hace mucho que dejé java y ando algo oxidado.

Comment: Que version del bot estas utilizando?

Comment: 3.5, que si no me equivoco es la última.

Comment: Hola @Pavl, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. ¿Estás importando la clase SendMessage? De acuerdo al código que anexas parece que no

Comment: Buenas, acabo de revisar el código y sí tengo incluidas lo siguiente: 
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;